# getting error during json parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I am getting error during  json parsing. When I trying to send the parameters using  browser then it send me the success message that record store successfully. But when I send form parameters through  iphone then i get nothing  and in array i get `NULL` value.This is the json parsing code.

```
  NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://195.78.76.34/bedspace/mobileapi.php?action=save_room_info&Area=%@&Address=%@&Living_room=%@&Amenties=%@&Type_of_cost=%@&cost_of_room=%@&Security_deposit=%@&STLC=%@&Days_available=%@&Bill_included=%@&Broadband_available=%@&Exc_Smoke=%@&Exc_gender=%@&Exc_pets=%@&Exc_age=%@&Exc_language=%@&Exc_nationality=%@&Exc_Sexorientition=%@&Exc_intrest=%@&Pre_smoke=%@&Pre_gender=%@&Pre_occupation=%@&Pre_pets=%@&Pre_min_age=%@&Pre_max_age=%@&Pre_nationaltiy=%@&Pre_Language=%@&Pre_Sexorientition=%@&Misc=%@&Title=%@&Description=%@&Your_name=%@&Your_email=%@&Email_alert=%@&No_of_rooms=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&State=%@&Size_of_property=%@&Type_of_property=%@&Occupets_property=%@&My_property_status=%@&Amenties_two=%@&Size_of_room=%@&Refrence_required=%@",area,address,livingRoomVal,amenties,typeOfCost,costOfRoom,securityDeposit,STLC,daysAvailable,billsIncluded,broadbandAvailable,eSmoke,eGender,ePets,eAge,eLanguage,eNationality,eSexOrientation,eInterest,pSmoke,pGender,pOccupation,pPets,pMinAge,pMaxAge,pNationality,pLanguage,pSexOrientation,misc,title,description,yourName,yourEmail,emailAlerts,noOfRooms,country,city,state,sizeOfProperty,typeOfProperty,occupentsOfProperty,myPropertyStatus,amentiesTwo,sizeOfRoom,refrenceRequired];
    NSLog(@"string 1 value %@",string1);
    NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:urlRequest];
   NSData *dataResponce = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:Nil error:Nil];

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResponce options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]; 
 NSLog(@"get values %@",publicTimeline);
```

I don't know what the problem is. I also used `SBJsonParser` but i get nothing in array and after that I used NSJSONSerialization and same problem still happen i got nothing in NSData and in NSArray.

Comment: what error log display?

Comment: Try to use NSMutableURLRequest and set HTTP method POST, this may help you

Comment: what is the parameter value?

Comment: brother i used this same code to store registration form records and it store successfully and i have done json parsing 100 of times to store the records in database and fetch records from database and get successfully i don't know why i getting error to

Comment: on nslog i getting null value in nsarray and also i log nsdata and it returning null as well

Comment: 2013-02-19 13:08:19.936 BedSpace[1230:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot fill the URL with parameters and still expect it to be legal, so you need to URL Encode the URL before use:

```
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:[string1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```